# Is there a way to select records from text parameters after run time in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to design a crystal report with 3 columns. Column 1 is a text box in the report, and column 2 and column 3 are datafields from a particular table.

Is it possible for me to use column1 as a parameter that would help me to fetch the other columns from the database??

col1      col2      col3

TextBox   value1   value2

so when a user changes the value in TextBox, col2 and col3 value should reflect based on textbox value.

Or is there any other way in which i can achieve this??

Comment: Where should user enter new value? Can you set that values in SQL queries (or where the data is prepared). In other way just write functions for 2 and 3 columns.

Comment: everything should happen within crystal reports design view....i create a textbox object, two columns from the db table, and somehow want to associate those two columns based on the text box value..So when i type in a value in textbox, the other two columns should be populated.

Comment: @cableload You would have to use a string parameter to change the output. More detail about what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: its kind of difficult to explain, but let me try my best...Lets say i have two columns A and B in my table, with column A a primary key for my table. My objective is to design a report with the same columns A and B. However instead of adding the column A via field explorer, i add a text box object and manually type the value. For column B, i drag it from DataBase fields. My objective is to have say around 15 rows from that table in a predefined order. I So would create 15 text box object in the report for column A, but column B would be populated based on textbox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if its important for the user to interact with the report after it's presented, you could accomplish this using (1) sections/grouping and Crystal's **Hide** option or (2) an on-demand subreport.

For example, you could group by column1, and then print a detail section for all the values. Mark the detail section **Hide**. Then, when you click on the value, that section will expand.

Or instead of marking it **Hide**, mark the group footer (for column1) **New Page After Section**. Then you can use the document tree along the left side to navigate to the page containing the values you're interested in seeing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to interact with a report the way you want via text boxes after the report has run. Since you can't select records on the fly, you'll have to create a report parameter of the same type as your primary keys (column A) and then set it to "Allow multiple values". You'll be able to select only the records you're looking for at run time by adding `{table.colA} in {?Parameter1}` into your Record Selection formula.

Drop {table.colA} and {table.ColB} into the Details section of the report. Now when you run it you can just add your 15 items as the parameter and you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok.....so should column 1 be created as a TextBox object in the crystal report design view or would it be a database field with a parameter applied to it??

Comment: ok..so i have created a parameter like you mentioned...and also have dragged both columnA and ColumnB(from database fields) into the report...so now how do i restrict the output to only those 15 rows by applying the parameter? I get a prompt asking me to select the values..i dont want all of that....

Comment: @cableload Column 1 will just be the database field {table.colA}.